# Error "Floating Point Error" en cálculo recursivo

Tags: pascal

estoy tratando de calcular de forma recursiva los elementos de una matriz de MxN. Al intentar dividir cada elemento de MxN da error de `Floating Point Error`.

```
function promMatRec(mNum:mat1;n,m,mMax:byte):real;
begin
if m>0 then
 promMatRec:=(mNum[n,m])/(m*n)+(promMatRec(mNum,n,m-1,mMax))
 else                                                         //porque se rompe si pongo m*n?
   if n>0 then
    promMatRec:=promMatRec(mNum,n-1,mMax,mMax);
end;
```

El de arriba compila.
El de abajo no.

```
function promMatRec(mNum:mat1;n,m,mMax:byte):real;
begin
if m>0 then
 promMatRec:=(mNum[n,m])/(9)+(promMatRec(mNum,n,m-1,mMax))
 else                                                         //porque se rompe si pongo m*n?
   if n>0 then
    promMatRec:=promMatRec(mNum,n-1,mMax,mMax);
end;
```

Estoy intentando hallar el promedio de esta matriz de MxN recursivamente, pero cuando divido por MxN a cada elemento me da `Floating Point Error`, y no entiendo bien porque, m y n están definidas como byte, aunque ya probe usando integer y sigo con el mismo problema.

Comment: Porque no calcula bien el promedio y no termina nunca...y sobre todo n toma el valor cero y por tanto divides por cero (if m>0 and n>0 then) por lo menos

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Por favor escribe un título explicativo (y conciso), parece que has empezado a escribir el mensaje directamente en el título.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si llama a la función cuando n=1 y m=0 entra por (n>0) a:

```
promMatRec(mNum,0,mMax,mMax);
```

como m>0(mMax>0)

```
promMatRec:=(mNum[0,mMax])/(mMax*0)+(promMatRec(mNum,0,mMax-1,mMax))
```

error: ***(mNum[0,mMax])/(mMax * 0)***

**Solucion:**

```
function promMatRec(mNum:mat1;n,m,mMax:byte):real;
begin
if m>0 then
 promMatRec:=(mNum[n,m])/(m*n)+(promMatRec(mNum,n,m-1,mMax))
 else                                                         //porque se rompe si pongo m*n?
   if n>1 then
    promMatRec:=promMatRec(mNum,n-1,mMax,mMax);
end;
```

Claro que la función no calcula la media porque n * m varia, tendría que ser constante(p.e nMax*mMax)